# How does this function: input.nn.MSECriterion_updateOutput(self, input, target) work (in Lua/Torch)?

Tags: function, lua, lua-table, torch

I have this function:

```
    function MSECriterion:updateOutput(input, target)
        return input.nn.MSECriterion_updateOutput(self, input, target)
    end
```

Now,

```
   input.nn.MSECriterion_updateOutput(self, input, target)
```

returns a number. I have no idea how it does it. I have walked step by step in the debugger and it seems this just computes a number with no intermediate steps.

```
 input is a Tensor of size 1 (say, -.234). And the 

 nn.MSECriterion_updateOutput(self, input, target) looks like it is just the function MSECriterion:updateOutput(input, target).
```

I'm confused as to how this can compute a number.

I'm confused as to why this is even allowed. The parameter input is a tensor, which doesn't even have any methods called nn.MSE input.nn.MSECriterion_updateOutput.

Answer (score 5):

When you perform `require "nn"` this loads `init.lua` which in turns performs a `require('libnn')`. This is the C extension of torch/nn.

If you look at `init.c` you can find [`luaopen_libnn`](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/3dd5d1d/init.c#L127): this is the initialization function called when `libnn.so` is `require`-ed.

This function takes care to initialize all parts of torch/nn, including the native parts of `MSECriterion` via `nn_FloatMSECriterion_init(L)` and `nn_DoubleMSECriterion_init(L)`.

If you look at `generic/MSECriterion.c` you can find the *generic* (i.e macro expanded for `float` and `double`) [initialization function](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/3dd5d1d/generic/MSECriterion.c#L47-L52):

```
static void nn_(MSECriterion_init)(lua_State *L)
{
  luaT_pushmetatable(L, torch_Tensor);
  luaT_registeratname(L, nn_(MSECriterion__), "nn");
  lua_pop(L,1);
}
```

This init function modifies the metatable of any `torch.FloatTensor` and `torch.DoubleTensor` so that it is filled with a bunch of functions under the `nn` key (see [Torch7 Lua C API](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/9b51907/lib/luaT/README.md) for more details). These functions are defined right before:

```
static const struct luaL_Reg nn_(MSECriterion__) [] = {
  {"MSECriterion_updateOutput", nn_(MSECriterion_updateOutput)},
  {"MSECriterion_updateGradInput", nn_(MSECriterion_updateGradInput)},
  {NULL, NULL}
};
```

In other words any tensor has these functions *attached* thanks to its metatable:

```
luajit -lnn
> print(torch.Tensor().nn.MSECriterion_updateOutput)
function: 0x40921df8
> print(torch.Tensor().nn.MSECriterion_updateGradInput)
function: 0x40921e20
```

*Note: this mechanism is the same for all torch/nn modules that have a C native implementation counterpart.*

So `input.nn.MSECriterion_updateOutput(self, input, target)` has for effect to call `static int nn_(MSECriterion_updateOutput)(lua_State *L)` as you can see on [generic/MSECriterion.c](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/3dd5d1d/generic/MSECriterion.c#L5).

This function computes the mean squared error between the input tensors.

Comment: How do you know that `init.c` is used for building `libnn.so`? I think it's done by *luarocks*, but I'm not sure how...

Comment: Luarocks supports cmake as build type. As you can see the [torch/nn rockspec](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/b7aa53d/rocks/nn-scm-1.rockspec#L20-L26) uses it. The [torch/nn CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/torch/nn/blob/b7aa53d/CMakeLists.txt#L44) contains a `SET(src init.c)` directive. Thanks to [torch cmake extensions](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/12ec0ad/cmake/TorchPackage.cmake#L8-L33) this is used to build the `libnn` library.